# Minisplit Head units produce heat far beyond set temp

Tags: heat-pump

My setup:
I have three C&H brand 9k head units upstairs in 3 different rooms. One 18k slim duct unit downstairs. And a 48k compressor outside.

The scenario:
It's 50° outside.
The three 9k units have a set temp of 65°. The temp in the rooms is 70° and they are idle and aren't producing heat. The 18k unit is off and the room temp is reading 68°.

The issue:
If I turn the 18k unit on and up to 72° it starts producing heat but at the same time the 3 9k units also start producing heat and don't stop even after they all hit their respective set temps.

It's 76° and climbing in all of the 9k unit rooms even though their set temps are still 65°.

Specifications:
The same issue happens when using the head units as the thermostat or the remote as the thermostat.

The question:
Why is this happening?

Comment: @ Landoperk, IDKWYATA?   Please use the full words to describe your issue. At least at the beginning of the question. Acronyms can be confusing.

Comment: Should we assume you're talking about mini splits or soemthing?

Comment: Heat-pump tag, head unit, duct unit, compressor, C&H is a brand...

Comment: @Landoperk I [edit]ed that info directly into the question (where it belongs) because it was very confusing and it took time to find the info down here in the comments. You're free to [edit] your own questions/answers any time you'd like to add more details, clarifying info, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The issue has been resolved.

**Root cause**
The culprit was a faulty management board on the compressor.

**Diagnosis**
One of the terminals was throwing irregular voltages. The manufacturer said this could have been caused by a defect from the factory or an unregulated power surge.

**Fix**
Replaced the board.

**Future Considerations**
Installed surge protector at compressor unit.

Comment: Great news! Thanks for coming back to post your solution. So many people can't be bothered... :(

Comment: Indeed. Please take the [tour], then accept your answer to resolve this question.